# Exception not able to get caught in catch block - Yii2

Tags: php, exception, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Exception

> Exception 'Error' with message 'Class 'app\commands\CallLogs' not
> found'

is not able to get caught in catch block.

Code:

I tried with calling undefined class just to see how and what exception catch block catches.

```
public function actionTest(){
    try {
        $logs = new CallLogs();
    } catch (\yii\base\Exception $ex) {
        print $ex->getMessage();
    } catch(\ErrorException $ex){
        print $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

But, When I intentionally throw any exception, it works.

```
public function actionTest(){
    try {
        throw new \yii\base\Exception('hello');
    } catch (\yii\base\Exception $ex) {
        print $ex->getMessage();
    } catch(\ErrorException $ex){
        print $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I have tried with base\Exception class and \ErrorException class. But, no help.

Any help/hint is appreciable

Comment: which version of php are you on?

Comment: php 7.4 @DonCallisto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`catch (\Throwable $e)` will do the job

[`\Throwable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) was introduced back in PHP 7.0 and is (quoting from docs) used for

> [...] any object that can be thrown via a throw statement, including
> Error and Exception.

Comment: Yes it worked @Don. And, I will mark it too. But, what was the reason it didn't came to catch block. Please don't mind, I'm just asking it for my future references.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Because a class not found is a `Fatal error` and couldn't be catched anyhow (even with `\Exception` base class). Moreover in your snippet, you are catching something very specific to `yii` and a specific subclass of `\Exception`